# Problem in understanding a statement on finding the velocity field of fluid.

Tags: calculus

I was reading [*The equations of motion*](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_40.html#Ch40-S1) of [*The Flow of Dry Water*](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_40.html) in *Lectures on Physics: Vol II* by *Feynman*; here he is explaining the equation of motion of incompressible fluid where $\bf v$ is the velocity of the fluid particle. Following is the concerned excerpt:

> [...] we get
>
> $$\frac{\partial\mathbf \Omega}{\partial t} + \nabla\times(\mathbf \Omega \times \mathbf v) = 0\;. \tag{40.9}$$
>
> This equation together with these equations $$\mathbf \Omega = \nabla\times \mathbf v\tag{40.10} $$ and $$\nabla \cdot \mathbf v= 0\tag{40.11}$$ describes completely the velocity field $\mathbf v\;.$  Mathematically speaking, if we know $\bf \Omega$ at some time, then we know the curl of the velocity vector, and we also know that its divergence is zero, so given the physical situation we have all we need to determine $\bf v$ everywhere. Thus, a given $\bf \Omega$ determines $\mathbf v\;.$ **Then, knowing $\mathbf v,$ Eq. $(40.9)$ tells us the rate of change of $\bf \Omega$ from which we can get the new $\bf \Omega$ for the next instant. Using Eq. $(40.10),$ again we find the new $\mathbf v,$ and so on.**

I could comprehend all but the blocked statements above.

He says if we know the $\bf \Omega$ at one time $t_1,$ then we can know $\bf v$ from $(40.10)\;;$ that's reasonable. But then he says using $(40.9)\,$ we can find $\mathbf \Omega$ at the next instant $t_2$.

Then he says, this should go "*so on*" - does that mean everytime we have to solve for $\bf v$ first and then using the same and $(40.9),$ we have to get the $\mathbf \Omega$ for the next instant?

Can't we find the function of $\bf \Omega$ in terms of time, $t,$ from the very first attempt solving $(40.9)$ for $\mathbf \Omega$ and using the value of $\Omega(t_1)$ as the initial value of $\bf \Omega\;?$

I didn't get why Feynman told to go on and on. Can't we have the function of $\mathbf \Omega$ in terms of $t$ and thus avoid doing the same thing *so on* ?

Comment: More in detail, Feynman is saying (40.10) and (40.11) together determine $\bf v$, given $\bf \Omega$ at some instant.  The evolution equation (40.9) is then appealed to, to take a "small" step forward in time and "get" $\bf \Omega$ at the "next instant".  This is somewhat hand wavy, but the author is a physicist after all, and is trying to convey an understanding of the information flow rather than a formal mathematical argument.

Comment: @hardmath: What I'm saying is that if he knows the value of $\bf \Omega$ at some instant, why can't he then find the function $\bf \Omega$ from $(40.9)$ using the given value of $\bf\Omega$ like as in initial-value problems? I didn't get why he told to go on and on.

Comment: I think just as he knows the value of $\bf \Omega$ at some instant, he can determine $\bf v$ only for that very instant; and not the function $\bf v\;.$ then the process of going on and on sounds reasonable.

Comment: @MAFIA36790, that's correct. This is an iterative scheme. However, $v$ is still a function, but it's a function of the space coordinates, at some instant $t_0$

Comment: @You'reInMyEye: thanks... got the point.